# How to use custom functions in ADO.NET Entity queries

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Does anybody know how to use custom functions in ADO.NET Entity queries?

```
var data = from w in _Context.Workers
select new WorkerData()
{
WorkTime = HoursMinsSecs(w.StartTime, w.StopTime);
};

public string HoursMinsSecs(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
TimeSpan span = (endTime - startTime);

return String.Format("{0} hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds",
                                 span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
}
```

I'm getting error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   HoursMinsSecs(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score -1):

It'is impossible, you have to write your own LINQ provider to make them work. But you can use EF canonical functions out of the box.